# Changing to first upper case letter when the first character is a number

Tags: php, ucfirst

I've done this in the past but no longer have what I wrote and can't remember how I did it previously. In correcting some user input, say "THIS IS AN ITEM" to "This is an item", I of course use

```
ucfirst(strtolower($text))
```

however it's no use when $text = "4 temperature controls"

I'm sure I had this sorted so "4 Temperature controls" was the output but can find no reference to ucfirst skipping non alphabet characters

Comment: Maybe a regex or a split

Answer (score 3):

Use regex for that:

```
$text   = "4 temperature controls";
$result = preg_replace_callback('/^([^a-z]*)([a-z])/', function($m)
{
   return $m[1].strtoupper($m[2]);
}, strtolower($text));
```

`ucfirst()` is simply not the use-case here, since it can not predict your following characters, it's working with first character always.

Comment: Try it with: `$text   = "php: A programming language";`. It will lowercase the `A`.

Comment: @hek2mgl that's OP's intention as I see

Comment: Probably this would handle the input string more *carefully*: http://3v4l.org/iVm5J . Also it does not need to strlower the whole string. (But probably not required, just a hint)

Comment: Well, it is. But - since OP was asking only about `ucfirst()` part, I've left that untouched (that's why you saw "A" lowercased in your sample). Thanks for the comment in any case

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php 
$str = "4 temperature controls";
preg_match("~^(\d+)~", $str, $m);
$arr = explode($m[1],$str,2);
echo $m[1]." ".ucfirst(trim($arr[1]));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's might be a better way, but using a simple `preg_match` should work:

```
$text = "4 temperature controls";
$match = preg_match('/^([^a-zA-Z]*)(.*)$/', $text, $result);

$upper = ucfirst(mb_strtolower($result[2]));
echo $fixed = $result[1].$upper;
```